# Edit Configuration Files on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am following [this link](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/) to configure the "Setup Hadoop 2.6.0 (Single Node Cluster)".
In step 4.2 "Edit Configuration Files" I exec the command `$ hdfs namenode -format`.
And this is what I have got:

```
/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 262: /opt/jdk1.8.0_31//bin/java: No such file or directory
/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 262: exec: /opt/jdk1.8.0_31//bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: It seems like the java binary is not where it thinks it should be.  If you run `ls -l /opt/jdk1.8.0_31/bin` what does it show?

Comment: What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` results in terminal?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME , I get this = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6.x86_64 (If it is important I am with user root@hadoop )